# Angular - filter by single ng-model, but on multiple properties?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following input data:

```
  $scope.postList = [{
    name: "Hello World #1",
    is_published: false,
    targeting: false
  }, {
    name: "Hello World #2",
    is_published: true,
    targeting: true
  }, {
    name: "Hello World #3",
    is_published: true,
    targeting: true
  }, {
    name: "Hello World #4",
    is_published: false,
    targeting: true
  }];
```

And now, I should be able to filter results (displayed using `ng-repeat`) from the following select.

```
<select ng-model="filterByCriteria">
   <option ng-value="published">Published</option>
   <option ng-value="published">Unpublished</option>
   <option ng-value="targeting">Custom Targeting</option>
   <option ng-value="public">Public</option>
</select>
```

As you can see, "Published / Unliblished" is related to `is_published` property, and "Custom Targeting / Public" is related to `targeting` property.

**Plnkr**: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ej8qSGCUbts0RVVJspM1?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:
Add this new Object

```
$scope.filterByCriteria = [{
    is_published: true
}, {
    is_published: false
}, {
    targeting: true
}, {
    targeting: false
}];
```

And in the HTML

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myController">
  <div>
    Filter by:
    <select ng-model="selectedCriteria">
      <option value="0">Published</option>
      <option value="1">Unpublished</option>
      <option value="2">Custom Targeting</option>
      <option value="3">Public</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="post in postList | filter: filterByCriteria[selectedCriteria]">
      {{post.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Here is an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ENfYs9EulmgGQ1dWrhA9?p=preview)

Comment: Have you tested it?

Comment: True, nice solution by the way. It just can be a problem if he can't create this object (in case of he doesn't know what properties the array of objects contains), considering, of course, it was just an example..